# Ajax: Send a model to controller from list iterated by foreach loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I need to be able to send a list of a model back to the controller from a view but only when the input has been checked.

Using AJAX I can get it working but the page refreshes and I don't catch the data but it does show up in the URL. Example: https://localhost:44308/PlayTest/PlayTest?personName=Test+User&DevOps-rate=3&Software+Development-rate=2&Solution+Architecture-rate=1&comments=&save=Save

But when I try and use Javascript and JQuery, I'm only able to catch the "person name" not the comments or rates in the post method.

**HTML**

```
<div class="tabcontent" id="testing">
  <form name="skillform"
        id="skillform"
        asp-action="SaveRecord"
        asp-controller="YourSkills"
        data-ajax="true"
        data-ajax-method="post">
      <h3 class="tab-title">Testing</h3>
      @foreach (var item in Model.Skills)
      {
          @if (item.SkillGroupID == 2)
          {
              <div class="star-rating">
                  <h5 class="skill-name" id="skill-title">@item.SkillName</h5>
                  <input type="radio" id="@item.SkillName@item.SkillGroupID-star3" name="@item.SkillName-rate" value="3" /><label for="@item.SkillName@item.SkillGroupID-star3" title="Advanced - 3 Stars">3 Stars</label>
                  <input type="radio" id="@item.SkillName@item.SkillGroupID-star2" name="@item.SkillName-rate" value="2" /><label for="@item.SkillName@item.SkillGroupID-star2" title="Intermediate - 2 Stars">2 Stars</label>
                  <input type="radio" id="@item.SkillName@item.SkillGroupID-star1" name="@item.SkillName-rate" value="1" /><label for="@item.SkillName@item.SkillGroupID-star1" title="Beginner - 1 Star">1 Stars</label>
              </div>
              <br />
              <br />
          }
      }
      <div class="comments">
          <h6 class="comment-name">Comments</h6>
          <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="comments" id="comment-text-area" spellcheck="true"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="buttons">
          <input type="reset" value="Clear">
          <button type="button" class="edit" onclick="alert('This will allow the tab to be edited')">Edit</button> <!--add cancel button when opened-->
          <input type="submit" name="save" value="Save" id="btnSave" skill-group="2"/>
      </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

**Post Method**

```
public JsonResult SaveRecord(string PersonName, List<SkillsModel> skill, string comment)
{
    SkillsMatrixDB database = HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(SkillsMatrix.Models.SkillsMatrixDB)) as SkillsMatrixDB;
    List<PersonModel> people = database.GetAllPeople();

    PersonModel recordingPerson = FindPerson(people, PersonName);

    if (skill.Count() > 1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < skill.Count(); i++)
        {
            RecordsModel records = new RecordsModel();
            records.PersonID = recordingPerson.PersonID;
            records.SkillGroupID = skill[i].SkillGroupID;
            records.SkillID = skill[i].SkillID;
            records.SkillLevelID = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Request.Form[skill[i].SkillName + skill[i].SkillGroupID + "-rate"]);
            records.Comments = HttpContext.Request.Form["comments"].ToString();
            records.DateSaved = DateTime.Now;
            records.YearlyQuarter = DateTime.Now.Month / 3;
            //database.SaveRecord(records);
        }
    }
    else if (skill.Count() == 1)
    {
        RecordsModel records = new RecordsModel();
        records.PersonID = recordingPerson.PersonID;
        records.SkillGroupID = skill[0].SkillGroupID;
        records.SkillID = skill[0].SkillID;
        records.SkillLevelID = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Request.Form[skill[0].SkillName + skill[0].SkillGroupID + "-rate"]);
        records.Comments = HttpContext.Request.Form["comments"].ToString();
        records.DateSaved = DateTime.Now;
        records.YearlyQuarter = DateTime.Now.Month / 3;
        //database.SaveRecord(records);
    }

    return Json(recordingPerson.Name);
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnSave").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: "POST", //HTTP POST Method
            url: "YourSkills/SaveRecord", //Controller/View
            data: $('#skillform').serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                alert('You saved it!');
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(textStatus);
                alert('Something went wrong. save failed!');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I feel like the way I've read to make the list in JS is wrong and to catch the data is not all that correct either. If someone could help that would be great. I'm so confused why doing it without JS works and picks up the right data but for some reason, I can't.

**EDIT**
I have tried what Emiel Zuurbier said but I am using Visual Studio 2019 and In the console, all I am getting is the following:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request starting HTTP/2.0 POST https://localhost:44308/PlayTest/YourSkills/SaveRecord application/json; charset=UTF-8 235
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request finished in 6.0162ms 404 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request starting HTTP/2.0 POST https://localhost:44308/PlayTest/SaveRecord application/x-www-form-urlencoded 233
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () [https://localhost:44308/PlayTest/YourSkills/SaveRecord]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware: Information: Executing endpoint 'SkillsMatrix.Controllers.PlayTestController.SaveRecord (SkillsMatrix)'
error
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker: Information: Route matched with {action = "SaveRecord", controller = "PlayTest"}. Executing controller action with signature Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.JsonResult SaveRecord(System.String, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[SkillsMatrix.Models.SkillsModel], System.String) on controller SkillsMatrix.Controllers.PlayTestController (SkillsMatrix).
```

Answer (score 0):

page reloading may happens because the error occurred in js execution while you are creating skills object.as its not the right way
define skills object this way rest of the things look good.

```
 let skills = {};
skills['SkillID']  = $("#skill-id").val();
skills['SkillGroupID']  = $(this).attr('skill-group');
skills['SkillName']  = $("#skill-title").val();
```

Comment: Unfortunatly this did not help the matter. But thank you any way :)

Comment: try creating your data object at the moment you click and then log it in the console to check if you are getting valid data   before  sending over ajax

Answer (score 0):

Your page is being reloaded because you are submitting the form whenever you click the the `#btnSave` button. What you want to do is listen for the `submit` event on the form itself and cancel it with `event.preventDefault()`. This allows you to create your own submission behavior when submitting. And prevents the form from reloading the page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#skillform').on('submit', function(event) {
    ...
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Your HTML seems to miss the `#skill-id` element. If you mean to include data from your form into your controller then I suggest that you use hidden input fields instead of reading attributes from your elements.

```
<input type="hidden" name="skill-name" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="skill-id" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="skill-group" value="">
```

These fields will not be visible to the user but will contain data that the server is able to read.

Then instead of use `.val()` to get each individual field use [`$('form').serialize()`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) to extract the name and value pairs out of the form and use them in your AJAX request. This way you are sending the same data as you would with a normal submit.

```
$.ajax({
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  dataType: 'json', 
  type: "POST",
  url: "YourSkills/SaveRecord",
  data: $('#skillform').serialize(); // <-- Get all values from the form.
  success: function (data) { // <-- data is the response you receive from the controller.
    console.log(data); 
    alert('You saved it!');
  },
  error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert('Something went wrong. save failed!');
  }
});
```

I recommend that you check the [`$.ajax`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-url-settings) docs to use the correct methods and notation to use the function properly.

Comment: I have changed to this but now it keeps doing the error state and when it calls the "SaveRecord" function only the "PersonName" gets populated. I see how the serialize will give me the same result as the url but why is it erroring and why would it not gether the form data properly.

Comment: Log the `textStatus` value in the error handler. Then look in your console to discover what the errors are saying.

Comment: I have tried this and posted the console in the original question as it is too large for this comment.

Comment: You are getting a 404 error. Meaning that your `"YourSkills/SaveRecord"` endpoint is never reached. Your original form does not specify a method, which means that it falls back to the `GET` method. So you could try changing `POST` into `GET` in the `$.ajax` function. I also saw multiple examples on the web which implemented an API structure with asp.net. Could be worth a try. [api tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: Ah thank you, I noticed that my Post method actually didnt have the [Http Post] tag on it as well which didnt help. The change from POST to GET helped me see the calls in Console so I can see it all now thanks.